# Not Update Laravel API One to Many Relationship data on Angular Frontend

Tags: php, angular, laravel, eloquent

I have Angular App connected with Laravel API. In Laravel API there are one to many relationship between Employee and Salary Models. when I try to update salary model it is not updating. but Employee model is update well. and postman updating for both models

I have Angular App connected with Laravel API. In Laravel API there are one to many relationship between Employee and Salary Models.
Employee.php

```
protected $fillable = ['birth_date','first_name','last_name','gender','hire_date'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no';

     public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no','emp_no');
    }
```

Salary.php

```
protected $fillable = ['salary','from_date','to_date'];

    public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

EmployeeUpdate Controller is

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    if (is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }
 $employee->update($request->validate([
        'emp_no' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'hire_date' => 'required'
]));
$employee->salaries()->update($request->validate([
'emp_no' => 'required',
        'salary' => 'required',
        'from_date' => 'required',
        'to_date' => 'required'

    ]));
    return response($employee, 200);
}
```

api route for update

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

my data.service.ts is like this

```
updateData(id: string, data: any) {
    return this.httpClient.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/'+id, data);
  }
```

and employee-edit.component.ts

```
updateEmployee() {
    this.dataService.updateData(this.id, this.employee).subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
      this.employee = this.data;
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

but when I try to update Employee Model data is updating well but not updating Salary Model data inspect encounting folllowing error
`bject { headers: {…}, status: 422, statusText: "Unprocessable Content", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1: 422 Unprocessable Content", error: {…} }`

but when I try Laravel API using postman without Angular it is updated successfully. what is the problem and how to fix this?
**edit**

```
I got following error with dd
@UnderDog when use dd it is getting `[webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement disabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled. polyfills.js:6253:28
Angular is running in development mode. vendor.js:47687:13
Object { emp_no: 1, birth_date: "1983-10-05", first_name: "devid", last_name: "John", gender: "male", hire_date: "2023-09-18", created_at: null, updated_at: null, titles: (1) […], salaries: (1) […] }
main.js:446:15
XHROPTIONS
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1
[HTTP/1 204 No Content 99ms]

XHRPUT
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1
CORS Missing Allow Origin

Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Origin)
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500.
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
vendor.js:33006:19
```

Comment: It seems like validation error and not a model error. Usually [422](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) errors when server cannot process the provided data maybe due to validation errors, although it understands the request.

Comment: what should I do fix this?

Comment: let's check the console first, can you update this `updateEmployee()` function in ` `employee-edit.component.ts` to properly handle error under subscribe using `(res) => {), (error) => {console.log(error)}`

Comment: So in your `updateEmployee` function you are using `$request->validate()` with an array of **required** fields. If one of those fields isn't filled in the data that you send through your frontend, you'll get that `422` error. Use `dd()` a lot, tl see what you are getting from your frontend. `validate()` also has an option to act if the 'validation has failed. Try those things first. And of course do your frontend thing with Angular, that's fine.